# FindViewById Loop

Tags: java, android, loops, view

I want to try and put this into a loop, but I can't seem to make the R.id.imageView to match. I tried : string id = "R.id.imageView"+i inside a for loop but it doesnt match the parameters for findViewById. Any ideas? greatly appreciate any help.

```
   buttons[0] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   buttons[1] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
   buttons[2] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
   buttons[3] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
   buttons[4] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
   buttons[5] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
   buttons[6] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
   buttons[7] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
   buttons[8] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
   buttons[9] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
   buttons[10] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
   buttons[11] = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take One Integer array for R.id.imageView1......12 and pass its value 
Like

```
private Integer[] Imgid = {R.id.imageview1,....,12  };
```

and use array

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
Resources res = getResources(); //if you are in an activity
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
   String idName = "imageView" + i;
   buttons[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res.getIdentifier(idName, "id, getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as above just typo fixed. Seems better than 'Best Answer' because you don't have to define any array if you don't need it.

```
Resources res = getResources(); //if you are in an activity
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
  String idName = "imageView" + i;
  imageViews[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res.getIdentifier(idName, "id", getPackageName()));
}
```