# How to create multiple objects using for loop and array

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and creating an app that have 30 spinners that share same content. How can I create these objects inside a loop without writing 30 lines ?

```
Spinner spinner_grade_1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grade_1);
Spinner spinner_grade_2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grade_2);
......
Spinner spinner_grade_30 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grade_20);
```

instead of that how can I create these objects inside a loop ? (I have created the following string array)

```
gradeBoxNames = new String[]{"spinner_grade_1", "spinner_grade_2",..... };
```

Comment: Why a `String`-array? Isn't it easier to create an [`android.R.id`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html)-array?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4865350)?

Comment: you can make `Spinner[] array;` and make another array of int ids like `int[] arr ={R.id.spinner_grade_1};` Now you can loop through these values like
`array[i] = findviewbyid(arr[i])`

Comment: Or using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626635) where you can say `String spinnerId = "spinner_grade_" + i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Initialize array of Resource ids

```
 int[] ids = {R.id.spinner_grade_1,R.id.spinner_grade_2};
        Spinner[] spinners = new Spinner[ids.length];


    for(int i=0 ;i< ids.length;i++) {
               spinners[i] = (Spinner) findViewById(ids[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

use [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library:

```
@Bind({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```